# Is musical formalism a better version of formalism (in the philosophy of mathematics) than game-theoretic formalism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, game-theory

There is a sense in which it is "true that" in the game of chess, a knight can move in an **L**-pattern, a queen can move in direct lines from end to end of the board, and pawns turn into queens if they cross the battlefield in full; or, then, that in transfinite forms of chess, various exotic strategies are or are not "winning" strategies; and so on. So it does not seem necessary to say that, if pure mathematics is its own kind of game, that it is purely arbitrary in the limit.

Still, logic too has been described in [game-theoretic ways (informed by Wittgensteinian considerations, even)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-if/#BacIFLogGamTheSem), and so it does not seem completely appropriate to confine working mathematicians' sense of "evidence for" their theorems only to the proof-theoretic realm. Deductive logic is sometimes accused of being technically uninformative, with conclusions being "mere restatements of the premises"; so would one really be justifying the presentation of a proof from arbitrary axioms, if acceptance of no axioms whatsoever could be arbitrated nontrivially in the first place?

Alternatively, then, instead of portraying the "empty" symbol-shuffling of pure math as a game (supposing it is empty), might it not be more "realistic" to portray it as akin to ***musical composition***? (This possibly aside from the fact that musical composition is subject to mathematical patterns of its own.) The nontrivial emptiness of mathematical derivations would then be compared to [emotional expressivity in alyrical songs](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/music/#MusiEmot), maybe. The justification of an axiom would consist in setting up a "theme" for a "deductive song," then; a theme that cannot be well-played would then be unjustified, so to say.

On the other hand, one could probably compare musical composition to game design, too. So maybe nothing would ultimately be gained by trying to separate the analogies. But I'm having a hard time thinking that pure mathematics, from semiotically random axioms, would resonate(!) with the motive of proof itself, if methods of proof are themselves game-theoretically random too.

Comment: I think "random" is not the right word. Maybe it should be replaced by "arbitrary", or "contingent", or "lacking necessity" - when multiple possibilities have all exhibit logical consistency.

Comment: @Frank maybe, but what then of paraconsistent logic and dialethism? However, if mathematical sentences are expressivistic more than factive, perhaps the distinction between alethic and dialethic (and trialethic, etc., for that matter) sentences becomes less troubling. We could say that e.g., "There exists an inaccessible cardinal," expresses truthfulness without being true like how a song can express happiness without having lyrics in which words like "happiness" occur, perhaps (I'm not sure what "expressing truthfulness" would really be, though).

Comment: One problem is that the concept of right and wrong or true and false doesn't really exist in musical formalism. Beethovens 5th is no more right or true than Stravinsky's Rite of Spring. The goal is to manipulate emotions not arrive at a truth.

Comment: @SteveSaban I made a poor choice of words by saying "musical formalism" since that phrase has a standard meaning in music studies. I should've said something about comparing musical notation to mathematical notation.

Comment: I believe what you are describing has been done in physics. Though not "musical", Feynman diagrams accomplish what you are describing. A pictoral representation of mathematical process used to elegantly describe the interaction of particles: Feynman diagram https://g.co/kgs/vh2Sju